# How can I invalidate() a android.view.View every 16 ms?

Tags: android, multithreading, frames

I know there are many Questions like this one but not even one answer worked for me!

EDIT 1: I want to program a "Pong" game. A method should recalculate and redraw the ball every frame.

Basically I am searching for an alternate way to do this this (**update a View every 16 ms to get a game running**):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    while (true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
t.start(); //here the code crashes
```

I've been through `Handler`, `TimerTask` ([link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)) and `Runnable` to list a few.

My best try was when I got a `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` with the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final GameView v = this;
final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        v.invalidate();
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, 100, 200);
```

EDIT 2: Best aproach by m0skit0:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
final GameView v = this;
final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!pause)
                    v.update(); //my invalidate()-method
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(task, 0, 16);
```

To everyone with a working idea: thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to `invalidate()` the `View` in the first place? Why do you want to do it every 16ms? `invalidate()` is a relatively expensive call, and one that is not usually necessary.

Comment: You can use `Activity#runOnUiThread()` to call your `invalidate()`, but you might want to answer CommonsWare's comment first. If you're making a game, consider a `Canvas` instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare i work with the `onDraw(Canvas c)`-method from `View`, so what else should I use rather than `invalidate()` to redraw?

Comment: Well, for a game, I would use a game development framework or engine, whether 2D or 3D, rather than working with the `View` system directly.

Comment: @m0skit0 thx this doesn't look very beautiful anymore but it finaly works. even if it is jerky...

Comment: You can also use `ViewCompat.postOnAnimation()` and reuse the same Runnable instance. It's used by Android animations to adjust to the system refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1:**
use `View.postInvalidate()` instead of `View.invalidate()`.
here is `postInvalidate()` [description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#postInvalidate()):

> public void postInvalidate ()
>
> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event
>   loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.
>
> This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when
>   this View is attached to a window.

**Suggestion 2:**
use [LIBGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) for games